# Cloud Data Fusion Wrangler stuck on enabling

Tags: google-cloud-data-fusion

trying to play with Data Fusion but the Wrangler is stuck on enabling:

[image]

Looking at the Dashboard, the Dataprep Service status is red:

[image]

Log:

```
2019-04-12 11:23:32,923 - DEBUG [provisioning-service-12:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@75] - Starting PROVISION task for program run program_run:system.dataprep.-SNAPSHOT.service.service.66a0ee78-5d15-11e9-b29e-02e34d3797c9.
2019-04-12 11:23:33,024 - DEBUG [provisioning-service-12:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@105] - Executing PROVISION subtask REQUESTING_CREATE for program run program_run:system.dataprep.-SNAPSHOT.service.service.66a0ee78-5d15-11e9-b29e-02e34d3797c9.
2019-04-12 11:23:33,024 - DEBUG [provisioning-service-12:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@109] - Completed PROVISION subtask REQUESTING_CREATE for program run program_run:system.dataprep.-SNAPSHOT.service.service.66a0ee78-5d15-11e9-b29e-02e34d3797c9.
2019-04-12 11:23:33,035 - DEBUG [provisioning-service-12:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@105] - Executing PROVISION subtask POLLING_CREATE for program run program_run:system.dataprep.-SNAPSHOT.service.service.66a0ee78-5d15-11e9-b29e-02e34d3797c9.
2019-04-12 11:23:33,036 - DEBUG [provisioning-service-12:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@109] - Completed PROVISION subtask POLLING_CREATE for program run program_run:system.dataprep.-SNAPSHOT.service.service.66a0ee78-5d15-11e9-b29e-02e34d3797c9.
2019-04-12 11:23:33,105 - DEBUG [provisioning-service-12:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@105] - Executing PROVISION subtask INITIALIZING for program run program_run:system.dataprep.-SNAPSHOT.service.service.66a0ee78-5d15-11e9-b29e-02e34d3797c9.
2019-04-12 11:23:33,111 - DEBUG [provisioning-service-12:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@109] - Completed PROVISION subtask INITIALIZING for program run program_run:system.dataprep.-SNAPSHOT.service.service.66a0ee78-5d15-11e9-b29e-02e34d3797c9.
2019-04-12 11:23:33,119 - DEBUG [provisioning-service-12:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@124] - Completed PROVISION task for program run program_run:system.dataprep.-SNAPSHOT.service.service.66a0ee78-5d15-11e9-b29e-02e34d3797c9.
2019-04-12 11:24:12,616 - INFO  [program.status:i.c.c.i.a.r.d.DistributedProgramRunner@488] - Starting Service Program 'service' with Arguments [logical.start.time=1555068210903, system.profile.name=SYSTEM:dataproc]
2019-04-12 11:36:25,625 - DEBUG [provisioning-service-13:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@75] - Starting DEPROVISION task for program run program_run:system.dataprep.-SNAPSHOT.service.service.66a0ee78-5d15-11e9-b29e-02e34d3797c9.
2019-04-12 11:36:25,718 - DEBUG [provisioning-service-13:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@105] - Executing DEPROVISION subtask REQUESTING_DELETE for program run program_run:system.dataprep.-SNAPSHOT.service.service.66a0ee78-5d15-11e9-b29e-02e34d3797c9.
2019-04-12 11:36:25,720 - DEBUG [provisioning-service-13:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@109] - Completed DEPROVISION subtask REQUESTING_DELETE for program run program_run:system.dataprep.-SNAPSHOT.service.service.66a0ee78-5d15-11e9-b29e-02e34d3797c9.
2019-04-12 11:36:25,734 - DEBUG [provisioning-service-13:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@105] - Executing DEPROVISION subtask POLLING_DELETE for program run program_run:system.dataprep.-SNAPSHOT.service.service.66a0ee78-5d15-11e9-b29e-02e34d3797c9.
2019-04-12 11:36:26,411 - DEBUG [provisioning-service-13:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@109] - Completed DEPROVISION subtask POLLING_DELETE for program run program_run:system.dataprep.-SNAPSHOT.service.service.66a0ee78-5d15-11e9-b29e-02e34d3797c9.
2019-04-12 11:36:26,421 - DEBUG [provisioning-service-13:i.c.c.i.p.t.ProvisioningTask@124] - Completed DEPROVISION task for program run program_run:system.dataprep.-SNAPSHOT.service.service.66a0ee78-5d15-11e9-b29e-02e34d3797c9.
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was a bug in the open source CDAP that hangs the start/stop of the wrangler service. You can find more information about that bug in https://issues.cask.co/browse/CDAP-15253

Answer (score 5):

Have not seen this behavior in my setup. Can you try to restart the service? You can do that by doing the following

1. Go to HTTPExecutor 
   https://InstanceURI/cdap/httpexecutor
2. Run a POST query to start 
   `namespaces/system/apps/dataprep/services/service/start`

[image: Start Wrangler Service]

Let us know if this fixes the issue.

Thanks,

Sree

Comment: Thank you for your answers but I am afraid it doesn't help. The POST request gives a 200 response and then the status turns orange. But the Wrangler interface still shows the Welcome to Wrangler page with the button to enable it (which still hangs). The log shows same PROVISION entries as in my original post. No DEPROVISION entries anymore though.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a new instance and everything works there.

Comment: We are able to recreate the scenario in our test setup and will soon release a patch with this fix: https://issues.cask.co/browse/CDAP-15253